# jQuery hover on the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery

With jQuery hover how do you check if you've just hovered on the same element again? Say I have two boxes and hover on box 1, then left, then come back and hover on that same box. I'd like to store the value of the initial hovered element (box 1) and then compare if it's the same when hovering back.

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you only want this to happen when you hover on the same element you were just hovering on? Or if you hover on any element more than once? Those are two different situations with two different solutions, both of which are outlined in the answers below... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like below,

```
var lastHovered = '';

$('#box1').hover(function () {
    if (lastHovered == 'box1') {
       alert('You have hovered on this already');
    }   
    lastHovered = 'box1';

    //Your stuff
}, function () {
    //mouse out stuff
});

$('#box2').hover(function () {
    if (lastHovered == 'box2') {
       alert('You have hovered on this already');
    }   
    lastHovered = 'box2';

    //Your stuff
}, function () {
    //mouse out stuff
});
```

**Note:** I have used 2 functions assuming that box1 hover and box2 hover has totally different functionalities... If not you can have it inside same function and use `this.id` to group them.. see below.

```
var lastHovered = '';

$('#box1, #box2').hover(function () {
    if (lastHovered == this.id) { //<-- used this.id instead of hard-coded value
       alert('You have hovered on ' + this.id + ' already');
    }   
    lastHovered = this.id; //<-- used this.id instead of hard-coded value

    //Your stuff
}, function () {
    //mouse out stuff
});
```

Comment: If you assign `this` to `lastHovered` instead of using hard-coded values, you can use the same callback for both elements. `$('#box1, #box2').hover( ...`

Comment: Using `this` is a good suggestion, but a simple string is lot smaller (prob `this.id` is a good way to go). Ans using same hover function depends on what OP is trying to do. It could have totally different `stuffs` inside each hover.

Comment: `this` is an object reference, which should be smaller than a string. True about the `stuffs` though... depends on the situation though. Could chain the hovers and use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

Use .data() http://api.jquery.com/data/ so on first hover in the callback do something like

```
if (!$(this).data('var')) {
    $(this).data('var','value');
} else {
    console.log($(this).data('var'));
};
```

Comment: good idea, but the $(this) value changes per element hovered, accessing the 'previous hover' .data() object would be rough.

Comment: If you read the question all the poster is asking for is a way when hovering the same element again, to track that that element was hovered already. He didn't ask anywhere to be able to track the last hovered element on each element that can be hovered. So .data would do just that. That's why the question has a comment, which was never answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastHovered = null;
$('#selector1,#selector2,#selector3').hover(function (evt) {
    if(lastHovered && lastHovered === $(this).attr("id")){
//code for 're-hovering'
    }else{
//code for 'new hover'
    }
}, function (evt) {
    //mouse out stuff
    lastHovered  =  $(this).attr("id");
});
```